# need to to sort directories based on the pattern yyyymmdd

Tags: perl, unix

I have a path where I will be creating many directories in the format "test_1.2.3_yyyymmdd"

> e.g. test_1.2.3_20140214

One common thing is , i will always have the date ( in yyyymmdd format) as part of the directory name. Ideally the files
get created in same fashion with different dates.

My requirement here is to sort files based on the date field in the directory name,which I am able to achieve with the below command

```
ls | sort -t_ -k3,3
```

But , there might be times when the directory gets created with the date not being the last field of the directory name. Even in such cases I want
to sort the files based on the date string. Can someone please tell me how to achieve this.

If i am able to achieve this sort , then i have to delete the oldest file ( based of yyyymmdd pattern ) . The requirement is the path should always contain latest 10
directories based on above sorting and if it is more than 10 , then i have to delete the oldest directories.

I cannot count on find command as this is not based `-mtime`

I want to rely on UNIX tools/Perl Programming for this.

Comment: Will your filenames each contain at most one substring of eight consecutive digits?

Comment: Hi Rob , there wont be any other part in the filename that will have eight consecutive digits . The occurrence of eight digit number (date yyyymmdd) will be only once

Comment: *"... i have to delete the oldest file ( based of yyyymmdd pattern ) ."*  What happens if two or more files have the same yyyymmdd?

Comment: It wont be that way, but yes , if it is, i have to delete them as well.

Comment: If you are unsure of the directory name to contain the correct timestamp, why don't you run 'stat' on the files, find correct timestamps and act appropriately. Why the need to rely on incorrect  and probably stale metadata.

Comment: @sateesh - That's a good question.  The OP, however, said, *"I cannot count on find command as this is not based -mtime."*

Comment: the date on the filename is date on which it was created. I dont want to rely on stat , as i am not concerned about the date on which it was modified. I want to preserve the data of last 10 runs . and also , we may run it continuously for a 2 weeks and then stop it for two months. We still want to hold last 10 runs data. 
At any point it has to hold 10 runs data. If its more than that it has to delete the oldest. so i am relying on the timestamp that appended in the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option to consider:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/min/;

my %files;

while ( my $file = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $file;
    my ($date) = $file =~ /([^_]+)$/;
    push @{ $files{$date} }, $file;
}

local $, = "\n";
print @{ $files{ min keys %files } };

__DATA__
test_1.2.3_20140214
test_A.B.C_20140214
test_X.Y.Z_20140212
test_1.2.3_20140210
test_4.5.6_20140210
```

Output:

```
test_1.2.3_20140210
test_4.5.6_20140210

$VAR1 = {
          '20140210' => [
                          'test_1.2.3_20140210',
                          'test_4.5.6_20140210'
                        ],
          '20140212' => [
                          'test_X.Y.Z_20140212'
                        ],
          '20140214' => [
                          'test_1.2.3_20140214',
                          'test_A.B.C_20140214'
                        ]
        };
```

Using `split` is preferred, but you mentioned that the date string might not be the last part of the file's name.  Thus, you need some way (`split`, regex, ...) to get it.

In the above script, these dates are use as the keys in a hash of arrays (HoA), and the values are references to lists of the file paths.  `min` from [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.38/lib/List/Util.pm) is used to find the min key value, as that would be the oldest date.

The HoA was used, in case there are multiple files which have the same yyyymmdd.

Instead of `print`ing the results, pass the array to [unlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) to delete the files, i.e., `unlink @{ $files{ min keys %files } };`.

A [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.22/lib/Data/Dump.pm) of the hash shows its structure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response , will try making use of your suggestion.
I felt best way is to , make check if the number of directories within path are greater than 10 and if it is , then  sort the files based on the yyyymmdd available and then do `$count=current_dir_count - 10` and then delete it `ls | sort -t_ k3,3 | head -$count | xargs rm -rf`

But my only concern is , what if the date is not the 3rd field of the filename :(

Comment: @chidori You're most welcome!  You said, *"...what if the date is not the 3rd field of the filename ..."*  That's definitely an issue that you need to address.

Comment: @chidori -  If the date string will *always* be the only eight digit number in the file names, you can do the following to capture it: `my ($date) = $file =~ /(\d{8})/;`

Comment: Thanks Kenonsis , and all who shared their views.
I am enhancing Kenonsis code , to match my requirement :)
when the directory count crosses 10 , i would need the list of old files , so i am sorting the keys and deleting the top files based on count of number of files that got created after the directory count crossed 10